# Mask special tags like PIN and Username while logging with logback

Tags: logback

i'm trying to use logback to mask more than one entry in the log file but it seems that the pattern tag not accept more than one replacement, please help me to mask more than one

here is what i do and working fine
    
    %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} -%replace(%msg{'<PIN>.*</PIN>',

    '<PIN>****</PIN>'}%n

but i want to add multiple replacement for example i want to add also the below but it didn't accept

%replace(%msg){'<Username >(.*)</Username>', '<Username >**</Username >'}%

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a common use case. Could you please [create a jira issue](http://jira.qos.ch/)  to ask for this feature?

Comment: did you ever get that JIRA created? because I need this too, or at least some other workaround. I have tried extending various classes in the appender/encoder/layout hierarchy, but have not had any success. Do you have any examples anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in https://github.com/tersesystems/terse-logback#censoring-sensitive-information and https://tersesystems.com/blog/2019/05/11/application-logging-in-java-part-3/ -- you can define a custom converter that will contain regular expressions.